# Multiple groups with the identical ids in LDAP using chef

Tags: linux, ldap, chef-infra

I have a group in LDAP that has a specific gidNumber. I want to be able to connect that group to multiple other groups with the same gid (each group exists on a different machine). Using chef, I am able to create a group on the machine that has the same gid as the group on LDAP. When I attempt to deploy another machine, the chef script fails to create the same group because the "gid is not unique". Is there anyway to connect the LDAP group to multiple other groups, all with the same gid?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `non_unique true` property on the group resource.

Comment: I have tried this and I am still getting
"groupmod -g '1111' testgroup returned 4, expected 0"

Comment: Looks like a bug in the Linux group provider code, we only pass `-o` for the initial create: https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/provider/group/groupadd.rb#L130